# using more than one PC with one screen

Tags: home-networking, display, switch

I have 2 computers that I want to use at the same time with [my screen](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&cc=us&docname=c01182749), doing some research I found that the best solution is to use the [KVM switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).

But my screen hp w2207h actually have standar VGA cable and HDMI connector and the 2 PCs support those connectors.

So my question is , can I use this screen plugging the VGA cable in one PC and the HDMI to the other without the need to any extra hardware? and if so how can I switch from a PC to another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well for example most Samsung Monitors with HDMI and VGA connectors have a source button where you can switch between the two signals. Using both is no problem at all. 
For using only one keyboard and mouse you might want to install [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) on both PCs which lets you share that hardware via the network.

Alternatively you can try a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) solution. The drawback there is that you might probably lose graphics performance with the remote controlled PC.

Check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/11052/how-can-i-control-two-computers-with-the-same-keyboard-and-mouse) as well.

Comment: thanx that's totally working, but a little question about Synergy: do I have to have 2 monitors in order for it to work

Comment: Hm not really. That is one of Synergys ideas to have some kind of multi monitor setup (1 monitor for one PC) and control them both with one keyboard. But I'm pretty sure that you can set Synergy up so that you e.g. press a key combination to switch to the other PC and then you have so switch the source on the monitor.

Comment: Synergy+ (http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/)

Answer (score 1):

I hooked up two computers to one monitor: one via DVI, the other via VGA.
I switch between the two displays by pressing a button on my monitor.

I share the same mouse/keyboard between both computers with a program called Magic Mouse. It lets you move across both computers as if they were a single desktop. You can also change the input focus to a single computer or up to four computers simultaneously with keyboard combinations. It might be an internal Microsoft tool; I will check if it's available outside MS. I know there are other similar programs, though.

Also another cool feature of Magic Mouse is that it lets you share clipboard contents across the different computers!

I stopped using a KVM because the one at work only supported PS/2 mice/keyboards.

Comment: that's an awesome answer, but I can't make it the best since I already did :)

Comment: KVM switches really have all kinds of nasty things. I do have one that supports USB, but only USB 1.1 which renders the USB 2 hub in my keyboard nearly useless. Also it switches on Scroll Lock twice which just happens to happen at each reboot. And upon starting up VMs in Virtual PC. I seriously wonder why monitors can switch input but haven't eveolved a switchable USB hub too.

Comment: You can also use synergy (http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) for that. That's cross platform.

Comment: hihiiii, so funny maybe the next question :)

Comment: Anybody got a link for Magic Mouse? Apple have just made that really hard to search for :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but it won't let me comment yet so posting this as an answer, [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460)'s a link to Magic Mouse that was referred to.